# Search bar with different queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a search bar on my website. If the searchbar is not set/NULL/empty the site should display all the records (so without the WHERE clause), if it's filled in, it should display the same records but with the WHERE clause (filtering it).

So, I thought since there 2 different searches (one with and one without WHERE), I should also create 2 different queries.

Problem I have is: if I test it and put a dump of both queries, both the variables are filled with the same query.

```
<?php

require_once 'somefile.php';

$user = new user();
if(isset($_POST['btnSearch'])){
  $searchTerm = $_POST['txtSearch'];
  $items2 = DB::getInstance()->get('items', array('Name', 'LIKE', '%['.$searchTerm.']%'));
  //should be: "SELECT * FROM items WHERE Name LIKE '%[my_search_term]%'
  //is: "SELECT * FROM items WHERE Id > 0"; --> not correct

  $items = DB::getInstance()->get('items', array('id', '>', '0'));
  //is: "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id > 0" --> correct
}
?>
```

html:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" class="ftco-section">
<div class="row">
      <input type="text" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" placeholder="Search..." />
      <button type="submit" name="btnSearch"><img name="imgSearch" id="imgSearch" 
src="images/search.png" /></button>
    </div>
</form>
...table to display the results
```

Any idea how this could come?

Edit: Found what was wrong, the 2nd query was in the wrong place, it was before the first one, so the 1st one always overwrote the 2nd one. Changed the place and now it works as it should.

Comment: We don't know what your `DB::getInstance()->get` does, so this can't currently be answered for certain. But if the debug output of your first query contains `WHERE Id > 0` already, which you did not specify there at all, then it looks like your database class might be messing things up somehow.

Comment: I think the if statement should be ```if (array_key_exists('txtSearch', $_POST) && $_POST['txtSearch']) {...}```

Comment: The reason I put the output there is indeed because you don't know what the {DB::get instance} does. But, to be honest, it exactly does what my output says, namely {SELECT * FROM (table_name) WHERE (field) (operator, aka 'LIKE' or >) (search term)}. The {DB::get instance} works fine, because if I don't put the 2nd variable there (so only the first one, where it displays everything) it works fine. It's only after I added the 2nd instance that the problem was there.

Comment: "put a dump of both queries" - what does that mean? Can you share more details, like the code you use for that?

Comment: Also, I hope you're using prepared statements anywhere in that code, such that the search feature won't be used to hack your database

Comment: Hi Nico. By 'a dump' I mean a var_dump. A way in php to just output a variable on the screen. To answer your other question, I do use a prepare statement, via the class I use, that's why my statement here is doesn't look like a normal SELECT you get from MySQL (i.e. DB::get()... )